# MariaDB LOAD DATA INFILE for null DATE field

Tags: mysql, mariadb, load-data-infile

I'm trying to load a tsv file into a mariadb table. One of the fields is a DATE that's nullable.
From what I gather, load data infile uses "\N" to identify null content but in this case it's a no go:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007) at line 1: Incorrect date value: '\N' for column 'delete_date' at row 1
```

Any ideas how I can import that data without writing specific CASE WHENs for the import? It's a part of a script that loads multiple tables so I don't want to treat this as a special case.

Leaving the field blank is of course an error as well:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '' for column 'delete_date' at row 1
```

I assume it's possible to import null values for dates so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> taken [from the mariadb knowledge base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/how-to-define-a-date-in-order-to-import-an-empty-date-from-a-csv-file/)

That error is thrown when the `sql_mode` server system variable is set to `strict` mode. If it's not set, you can enter a blank date - a warning is generated and '0000-00-00' will be inserted.

If you can set strict mode `off` for the duration of the import, that should work, otherwise you'll need to replace the blank date columns in the CSV with NULL, or '0000-00-00'.

Comment: Ah good find. NULL doesn't work (no big surprise there) but thankfully 0000-00-00 does because I didn't want to turn strict mode off otherwise.
Thanks!